# Arithmetic Operator Overloading C++

Tags: c++, overloading

I am new to C++ and am trying to understand overloading to get my arithmetic operators to overload successfully. Here is the code that doesn't compile.

```
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator*(const ComplexNumber& rightOp) const
{
double newValue = realNumberValue * rightOp.realNumberValue;
return ComplexNumber(newValue);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 2):

```
return ComplexNumber(newValue);
```

There is no constructor of ComplexNumber which accepts only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any constructor that take one value(double) as a parameter 
Add this to your implementation file

```
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double val)
{
double complexNumberValue = val;
double realNumberValue = 0;
}
```

This will fix the issue but you have to figure out yourself what to do for the logic part

Answer (score 0):

You only have a two argument constructor, but you are trying to invoke a single argument constructor.